# Python socket.getdefaulttimeout() is None, but getting "timeout: timed out"

Tags: sockets, python-2.7, timeout

How can I determine what the numeric timeout value is that is causing the below stack trace?

`...
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 548, in read
    s = self._safe_read(self.length)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 647, in _safe_read
    chunk = self.fp.read(min(amt, MAXAMOUNT))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
timeout: timed out`

After importing my modules, the result of `socket.getdefaulttimeout()` is `None` (note that this isn't the same situation as what produced the above, since getting those requires an 8-hour stress run on the system).

My code is not setting any timeout values (default or otherwise) AFAICT. I have not yet been able to find any hint that 3rd party libraries are doing so either.

Obviously there's some timeout somewhere in the system. I want to know the numeric value, so that I can have the system back off as it is approached.

This is python 2.7 under ubuntu 12.04.

Edit:

The connection is to localhost (talking to CouchDB listening on 127.0.0.1), so NAT shouldn't be an issue. The timeout only occurs when the DB is under heavy load, which implies to me that it's only when the DB is getting backed up and cannot respond quickly enough to requests, which is why I would like to know what the timeout is, so I can track response times and throttle incoming requests when the response time gets over something like 50% of the timeout.

Comment: Could you provide more info when it happens? Is it after long inactivity on the wire? Or is client behind NAT?

Comment: @RobertT: Sorry, I should have provided that to start. See edits.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing anything more my guess would be that NAT tracking expires due to long inactivity and unfortunately in most cases you won't be able to discover exact timeout value. Workaround would be to introduce some sort of keep alive packets to your protocol if there's such a possibility.